# setContentView Error in MainActivity Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am experiencing an error which I'm pretty sure has nothing to do with my code. I'm using Android Studio.

This error came about when I renamed a separate activity XML file and it prompted me if I wanted it to auto update the file with the new name which I allowed. I then saw an error on my MainActivity.java. After inspection I saw that the error came from the `R` in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.

```
package nz.school.app.nb;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inits the activity
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("Home");
    }

    // Timetable button listener
    public void timeTableButtonListener(View view){
        Intent kamarActivity = new Intent(this, TimetableActivity.class);
        startActivity(kamarActivity);
    }

    // Contacts button listener
    public void contactsButtonListener(View view){
        Intent contactsActivity = new Intent(this, ContactActivity.class);
        startActivity(contactsActivity);
    }

    // Links button listener
    public void linksButtonListener(View view){
        Intent linksActivity = new Intent(this, LinksActivity.class);
        startActivity(linksActivity);
    }

    // Notices button listener
    public void noticesButtonListener(View view){
        Intent newsActivity = new Intent(this, NoticesActivity.class);
        startActivity(newsActivity);
    }

    // Events button listener
    public void eventsButtonListener(View view){
        Intent eventActivity = new Intent(this, EventsActivity.class);
        startActivity(eventActivity);
    }
}
```

I then had a quick look online with nothing that would help. I decide to revert to my previous version with no errors but the same thing happens. I then remove the whole app folder and replace with my friend (We are both developing app) as he has the older version on his machine. After that the problem seemed to disappear which made me very happy. The next day I open the `MainActivty.java` and as soon as the file was opened the error came back.

I am now very confused to what this issue is from.

Comment: This can happen by many ways like there is some error in your  code or XMl or try to import R in your class with packagename.R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean your project (**Build>Clean**) and make sure all sdk packages installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

And a custom class with your project namespace:

```
import nz.school.app.nb.R;
```

Comment: @SillySam see my answer.

Comment: when OP has written Android Studio then why telling him shortcts of eclipse??

Comment: @VivekMishra now better or not ?

Comment: better than before

Answer (score 1):

try to `import nz.school.app.R` not `import nz.school.app.nb.R;`  after that try **Clean Project** and then **Rebuild Project** from Build menu and click **sync project with gradle file** icon  and but if you face still same problem then look at very carefully to you `xml` file if you found any error  there then fix it and try same process.